# $E(X_i \cdot I(X_i>\theta)$ expected value of when X is greater than the median.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be iid with a distribution F.

Let $\theta$ be the median of F.

What is the value of $E(X_i \cdot I(X_j>\theta))$?

If $i\neq j$, then $E(X_i \cdot I(X_j>\theta))= 1/2 \cdot \mu$, right?

When $i=j$, I don't seem to find it...

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $I$? Also, please fix the parens.

Comment: $I$ is the usual notation in statistics for the indicator function.

Comment: There is no simple formula for $E(X;X\gt\theta)$ in terms of $E(X)$ and $\theta$. It all depends on the underlying distribution $F$. *Exercise:* Find examples of $F$ such that $E(X;X\gt\theta)$ is a large/small as one wants when compared to $\theta$.

Answer (score 0):

Break it up into two using conditional expectation:

$E(X_i \cdot I(X_i>\theta))=P(X_i\leq\theta)E(X_i \cdot I(X_i>\theta)|X_i\leq\theta)+P(X_i>\theta)E(X_i \cdot I(X_i>\theta)|X_i>\theta)=\frac{1}{2}[0+ E[X_i|X_i>\theta]]=\frac{E[X_i|X_i>\theta]}{2}$

**That's as far as you can go without knowing the specific distribution.**

Comment: @StefanHansen oops...copy and paste typo

Comment: Really a mere rewriting of the expression in the question.

Comment: @Did Yes...but OP seems to think that an exact expression akin to $\frac{1}{2}\mu$ may be forthcoming.

Comment: Then stress **this** instead of embarking on formal manipulations leading nowhere...

Comment: @Did stress added ;-)

Comment: @Did also, it may be apparent to you, but it didn't seem evident that this was the case to the OP, so the derivation shows how to get to the "restatement" of the question. The version using conditional expectation shows why there's no simple answer to his question, which  may not be apparent from the indicator function expression.

Comment: I fail to see why the absence of a simple answer to E(X|A) should be more (or less) obvious than the absence of a simple answer to E(X;A)... :-)

Comment: @Did Many thanks to both of you.

May I interest you in the original question that prompted this last one? 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880715/prove-joint-distribution-of-estimators